# Experience moving from Bamboo to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, bamboo

I was curious if anyone out there has moved from Bamboo to Jenkins?

I have several hundred plans to migrate all using different kinds of languages, plans, and build strategies and would like to move them to Jenkins.  I've moved a few Java ones, but was curious if there was a good resource or 'best practices' for doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: I've no experience doing this, but out of interest, why do you want to move from Bamboo to Jenkins?

Comment: I'm aware of the fact responding to a fairly old post, however, did you ever find a solution for the Bamboo -> Jenkins migration?